# Huffman Decoding program problems

Tags: c++, struct, tree

I am trying to write a HUffman decoding algorithm.  I have decided to take an iterative approach.  I believe the main problem I am having has to do with my nodetype struct.  In DDD, it says that there is no right *child.  Any suggestions as to why this may be?  I have searched all over and have found no solutions to my problem.  Any suggestions?

I have omitted the rest of my program for simplicity.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned int uint;

struct nodetype
{
  // constructor
  nodetype( char symbol, nodetype * left, nodetype * right) :
    symbol( symbol ), left( left ), right( right )
  { }

  char symbol;
  nodetype* left;
  nodetype* right;
};

void createDecodingTree(  nodetype* root,
                        nodetype* &iter, 
                        string &codeSubstring, 
                        char leaf )
{
string code = codeSubstring;
nodetype* newLeaf = new nodetype( leaf, NULL, NULL );

uint index = 0;
uint codeLength = code.length();
iter = root;
//traverse through the code until the second to last bit
//for( uint i = 0; i <= code.length()-1; i++ );
while( codeLength - 1 > 0 )
{
    if( code.at(index) == '0' )
    {
        if( iter->left == NULL )
        {
            nodetype* newLeft = new nodetype( '\0', NULL, NULL );
            iter->left = newLeft;
            iter = iter->left;
        }
        else{
            iter = iter->left;
        }
    }
    if( code.at(index) == '1' ) 
    {
        if( iter->right == NULL )
        {
            nodetype* newRight = new nodetype( '\0', NULL, NULL );
            iter->right = newRight;
            iter = iter->right;
        }
        else{
            iter = iter->right;
        }
    }
    codeLength--;
    index++;
}   
//now make a new leaf based on the last bit
if( code.at( code.length() - 1 ) == '0' )
    iter->left = newLeaf;
else{
    iter->right = newLeaf;
}
}
```

And this is how I initialize my root.

```
nodetype* root = new nodetype( '\0', NULL, NULL );
```

Comment: did you mistakenly type right as child somewhere? the code you have shown is not enough to spot errors.

Comment: I included my decoding algorithm, hope that helps!